# CrudRepository not able to perform any queries on h2 db

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, h2

I am new to spring data. I have a h2 db in my app as well as a rest controller. Essentially I have a few endpoints which you call to perform certain queries. The endpoint will use the itnerface which extends crudrepository and perform the queries. The problem is that I call the endpoints but the crudrepository doesn't seem to find anything in the db. I accessed the db console and I can see my prefilled data which I seed the db with using `data.sql`.

This is what I have:

```
@Repository
public interface EmployeeRepository extends CrudRepository<Employee, Long> {
}
```

This is my entity:

```
@Entity

public class Employee {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
private String firstname;

public Employee(){}

public Employee(String firstname, String lastname, String email) {
    this.firstname = firstname;
    this.lastname = lastname;
    this.email = email;
}

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getFirstname() {
    return firstname;
}

public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
    this.firstname = firstname;
}

public String getLastname() {
    return lastname;
}

public void setLastname(String lastname) {
    this.lastname = lastname;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

private String lastname;
private String email;
}
```

Controller:

```
@RestController 
public class EmployeeController {

@Autowired
EmployeeService employeeServices;

@GetMapping("/getAllEmployees")
public void getAllEmployees(){

    //Add employee to db via spring data
    employeeServices.getAllEmployees();
}

@GetMapping("/deleteEmployee/{id}")
public void delete(@PathVariable Long id){

    //Delete employee to db via spring data
    employeeServices.deleteEmployee(id);
    System.out.printf("Deleted");
}

@PostMapping("/createEmployee")
public void create(@RequestBody Employee employee){
    //Add employee to db via spring data

    Employee save = employeeServices.createEmployee(employee);
    System.out.println("created: " + save.toString());

}
```

}

And my service:

```
@Service
public class EmployeeService
{
@Autowired
EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;

public void getAllEmployees(){
    List<Employee> listOfEmployees = new ArrayList<>();
    employeeRepository.findAll().forEach(employee -> listOfEmployees.add(employee));

    System.out.println(listOfEmployees);
}

public void deleteEmployee(Long id){
    employeeRepository.deleteById(id);
    System.out.println("deleted.");
}

public Employee createEmployee(Employee employee){
    employeeRepository.save(employee);
    System.out.println("saved.");
    return employee;
}
}
```

And this is my application.properties:

```
#Server
server.port=9975
# H2
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/h2
# Datasource
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:./fileOrDbName
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
```

And my data.sql:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TBL_EMPLOYEES; CREATE TABLE TBL_EMPLOYEES (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT  PRIMARY KEY, first_name VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL, last_name VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL, email VARCHAR(250) DEFAULT NULL); INSERT INTO TBL_EMPLOYEES (first_name, last_name, email) VALUES ('Lokesh', 'Gupta', 'abc@gmail.com'), ('Caption', 'America', 'cap@marvel.com');
```

The application starts fine and I can access the db console via `localhost:9975/h2` but the controllers crud doesn't seem to accessing the db. Any ideas?

Comment: what happens when you run localhost:9975/getAllEmployees from your browser ?

Comment: It prints out an empty list as opposed to a list of employees so that to me suggests the crudrepo is not communicating with the db? @georgesvan

Comment: your repo seems to be working fine. My guest is that your db is empty. you can check by running SELECT * FROM TBL_EMPLOYEES from isnside your H2 Database Console

Comment: Yup I've done that and I can see 3 entries and they're the entries I've included in my data.sql file

Comment: https://howtodoinjava.com/wp-content/downloads/spring-boot-hibernate-crud-demo.zip is the exact same Employee app. I downloaded it and it works.

Comment: Found out the problem. It was because I didn't annotate the fields in my entity class with the `@Column(name="..")` and didn't annotate the class with `Table(name="TBL_EMPLOYEES")`. Also needed to add the following in the application.properties file `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect`

Answer (score 2):

Found out the problem. It was because I didn't annotate the fields in my entity class with the `@Column(name="..")` and didn't annotate the class with `Table(name="TBL_EMPLOYEES")`. Also needed to add the following in the application.properties file `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect`

Comment: glad you found the solution.
also no need to add @Column to all fields, if your variable naming is similar to your table field names.